# Airflow basic authentication hides Admin -menu options

Tags: airflow

I enabled basic authentication in Airflow, but now I can't see most of the Admin -menu items. For example I can't create connections using the UI.

I'm using apache-airflow 1.10.2 and in the config I set:

> authenticate = True
>
> auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth

Answer (score 4):

When creating a new user:
[You can follow the directions here](https://airflow.apache.org/security.html#password). Then you should also make the user a "superuser".

```
# after user.password = 'set_the_password'
>>> user.superuser = True
...
```

If you already created the user you can change it this way:

```
$ python
>>> import airflow
>>> from airflow import models, settings
>>> from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser
>>> session = settings.Session()
>>> user = session.query(models.User).filter(models.User.username == {{ username you previously created }}).first()
>>> user.superuser = True
>>> session.add(user)
>>> session.commit()
>>> session.close()
>>> exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the admin functions the user must be in the Admin role. You can create an admin user with the [Airflow CLI](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#create_user):

```
airflow create_user -r Admin -u myadmin -p secret_password
```

Comment: RBAC is not enabled. I just need the basic authentication to work.

Comment: I enabled RBAC and the menus are fine, but now the webserver base_url -setting is not working. I'm deploying to ECS behind a load balancer and need to use url like:

https://<domain>:8080/airflow/admin

Probably need to add something to webserver_config.py to make it work.